# How do I update a JTable to display data from a new model?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am using the NetBeans GUI builder to create a `JTable` from an original `DefaultTableModel` which contains some placeholder data. When a specific action is performed in the GUI, the model needs to change to contain totally new data.

The table's initialization code is as follows:

```
tblMenu = new javax.swing.JTable(tblmodelMenu);
```

and the table model's initialization code is:

```
tblmodelMenu = new DefaultTableModel();
```

Right now, I am simply redefining the variable for the model to be a new `DefaultTableModel` with the desired data.

```
tblmodelMenu = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnHeadings)
```

where I have initialized `data` as a 2D array of `Object`s containing the desired data and `columnHeadings` as an array of `String`s.

However this just leaves me with a table displaying the original model. I am struggling to find a solution. I feel as though this should be a simple problem to solve, and I have read through old stack overflow questions which seem to tackle similar problems, however the answers seem to be outdated and use methods that seem unavailable right now.

Minimal reproducible example:

```
DefaultTableModel tblmodelMenu = new DefaultTableModel();
JTable tblMenu = new javax.swing.JTable(tblmodelMenu);

void updateTable(Object[][] data, String[] columnHeadings) {
    tblmodelMenu = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnHeadings);
}
```

The `updateTable` method should then be called with appropriate arguments. The content of the `data` and `columnHeadings` do not matter when trying to reproduce the result, as long as they do contain data that should be displayed.

Comment: Without a [mre] added to your question, all we can do is guess.  Normally, you create one DefaultTableModel with the correct column headers and change the row data within the DefaultTablkeModel.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Thanks, I added an example. How would I add/remove data from the table? Would I have to use the `setValueAt` method for each cell?

Comment: The [DefaultTableModel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html) has an addRow method and a removeRow method.  You use both these methods in a loop to add multiple rows and remove multiple rows, respectively.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Ah, thank you. I realise now where my struggles have come from. Lost in my variable declaration code was the line that declares my table as a `TableModel`. I thought I was going crazy when I initialized it as a `DefaultTableModel` but couldn't get any of the methods to work.

Comment: Creating a model does nothing. The model has not been added to the table. You need to use `table.setModel(...)` to actually add the data in the new model to the table.

Comment: Any chance we're going to see the MRE suggested by @GilbertLeBlanc in the first comment? If you have further trouble solving this, please edit to add one.